# Git Checkout Cannot Back to Master

Tags: git

I'm checking my code because there's a bug that I need to trace back into few days ago by using this command :

```
git checkout 35edc63
git checkout 3d09bbc
git checkout e450a0a
```

basically, I'm jumping from one commit into another commit to check which commit cause the bug.

once I found the bug, I cannot go back to the master commit, I tried to use this command to back to the master :

```
git checkout master
```

and here's the error message :

```
error: Entry 'error_log' would be overwritten by merge. Cannot merge.
```

I tried to delete the 'error_log' file as well, but still cannot go back to master. what did I do wrong? thank you.

Comment: do you have uncommitted changes you want to discard?

Comment: What does `git status` show you?  Doing `git checkout master` should be putting you back where you want to be.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : here's the `git status` : # Not currently on any branch.
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
# new file:   error_log
#
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
# deleted:    error_log
#

Comment: @Francesco : no, I never did uncommit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a hard reset to the last detached commit you were on, then just checkout the `master` branch from there:

```
git reset --hard e450a0a
git checkout master
```

If there be any files still sitting around in your working directory, then do this:

```
git clean -f -d
```

Disclaimer: This answer assumes that you *don't* want to retain any changes you might have made.  So it is appropriate as a safe escape from looking around other commits, but it is another story if you want to keep any work you have done.

Comment: probably it is not necessary to specify the commit. `git reset --hard` is enough. btw, he had uncommitted changes ;)

Comment: I added the SHA-1 in there because I thought he might have wandered from the commit where he actually made changes.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : works like a charm, bro. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try this command

```
git reset HEAD --hard
```

using this command it'll reset to your latest commits on the same branch, if you need the latest on master do the following command on the resetted branch

```
git pull origin master
```